# Is it possible to load a package before the LyX preamble?

Tags: lyx

I was wondering if it was possible to edit the packages that LyX load before the preamble. When I use XeLaTeX, LyX loads the package `fontspec`. The problem is that I load in the preamble the package `cmbright` and if I do it in this order the text turn to serif. From the exported TeX file from LyX I switched the order of the two packages (first `cmbright` and then `fontspec`) and it works perfectly. So does anybody know how to edit the packages that LyX automatically load?

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: If you're not using fonts other than `cmbright`, you don't need to use XeLaTeX; pdfLaTeX should be fine.

Comment: Yes it works perfectly with pdfLateX but I need XeLatex for local changes in the font

Comment: @Fabien If you are going to cross-post, please link to all of your other posts. To understand why, read about [free pizza](http://latex-community.org/home/latex-community/94-etiquette/454-crossposts)

Comment: One of the other posts is here: https://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg99707.html

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. I thought that the mailing list was just local and was not available on the web afterwards.

Comment: No problem at all. But in that case you could have still posted a link to your SE question there and here you could have said that you sent an email to the lyx-users list.

Answer (score 1):

I do not *know* this, as I'm not really familiar with the internals of LyX, but I suspect that the answer is no - you cannot (easily) edit the loading order of packages.

A workaround is however possible:

I assume you have selected *Use non-TeX fonts* in Document --> Settings --> Fonts. This adds, as you say, the `fontspec` package to the preamble. It may also have added  `\setmainfont{..}`, `\setsansfont{..}`, and/or `\setmonofont{..}`. Copy all of these lines, and paste them into the LaTeX preamble in the document settings. Then add the `cmbright` package in the correct location.

You can now unselect the *Use non-TeX fonts* option. Finally, go to the *Output* section of the document settings, and choose *PDF (XeTeX)* as default output format. That way, Ctrl + R will use XeLaTeX to build your PDF.